# Fresh magento 1.9.2.4 Installation error "customer_entity" table already exist in php 7

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am stuck fresh magento 1.9.2.4 installation.

It is thrown mysql error "customer_entity" table already exist.

this is the error that I got

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1719:"Error in file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\sql\customer_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'customer_entity' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `customer_entity` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Entity Id' ,
  `entity_type_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type Id' ,
  `attribute_set_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set Id' ,
  `website_id` smallint UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Website Id' ,
  `email` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Email' ,
  `group_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Group Id' ,
  `increment_id` varchar(50) NULL COMMENT 'Increment Id' ,
  `store_id` smallint UNSIGNED NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Store Id' ,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL default 0 COMMENT 'Created At' ,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL default 0 COMMENT 'Updated At' ,
  `is_active` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT 'Is Active' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID` (`email`, `website_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_WEBSITE_ID_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COMMENT='Customer Entity' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci";i:1;s:1052:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.2.0.4')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.2.0.4')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\webappmatemagmimport\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:57:"/webappmatemagmimport/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/";s:11:"script_name";s:31:"/webappmatemagmimport/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation was not done properly. May be it was run previously and was interrupted and now again when you tried to run, you are getting such error.
Don't have to worry, simply rename the php file that is running the script and continue the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a new database in phpmyadmin and remove local.xml and reinstall.
DOing this will remove the aforesaid error to ensure hassle-free installation.